# File Upload To Server

Tags: ios, data-structures

Is there any way I can read the data in range only and upload to the server. Example: Suppose if I have a video of 1 Gb so first I read 0 - 50 MB and upload to server and then 50 - 100 Mb and upload and so on.

Comment: First of all convert into NSData then divide the that data into different different chunks and then that chunk encodeusing base64 that send to server side.

Comment: While converting into NSData for bigger file app is crashing because of memory issue.

Comment: it will take lots of time to convert it to base64 , may be hours.You will have to divide that video yourself into small parts.and them will have to upload those parts. then you will have to merge those parts on server side.this can be a quick solution for your case.

Comment: Is there any way i can achieve using inputstream.

Comment: You will have to use wowza services or some streaming engine to do that then.It will upload your video while recording.

Comment: No, I need to upload any file from my iPhone. I can upload a photo, video, contact anything. But while converting a huge file into NSData using do { let data = try Data(contentsOf: Url) app get crash. Earlier I creating chunk only and uploading to a server but for bigger file how I create chunk while converting into NSData app get crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187506/discussion-between-farooque-azam-and-logic).